# Watermarking photos using geotag and creating shapefile from coordinates?

Tags: python, open-source-gis, geotag, exif

I have geotagged photographs and I would like to place a watermark of the photos location on the front for easy reference as well as creating a shapefile from the coordinates.

Does anyone know of any open source software which could do this?

[This link is an example of what Iam trying to acheive](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0911/graphics/photomap_1_lg.jpg)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use python for getting EXIF info:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from pprint import pprint

def getexif(im):
    res = {}
    try:
       img = Image.open(im)
       info = img._getexif()
       for tag, val in info.items():
           dec = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
           res[dec] = val

    except IOError:
       print im
    return res
    pprint res
```

then use python ImageDraw module for drawing text or anything.

```
import ImageFont, ImageDraw

def drawtext(im):
   op = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
   fnt = ImageFont.truetype("tahoma.ttf", 12)
   op.text((5, 5), "YourText", font=fnt)
```